# Stereo to Mono wav in Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I am loading a wav with the scipy method wavefile.read() which gives me the samplerate and the audiodata

I know that this audio data if stereo is stored as a multi-dimensional array such as

```
audiodata[[left right]
          [left right]
          ...
          [left right]]
```

I am then using this method to create a new array of mono audio data by taking (right+left)/2

```
def stereoToMono(audiodata)
    newaudiodata = []

    for i in range(len(audiodata)):
        d = (audiodata[i][0] + audiodata[i][1])/2
        newaudiodata.append(d)

    return np.array(newaudiodata, dtype='int16')
```

and then i write this to file using

```
wavfile.write(newfilename, sr, newaudiodata)
```

This is producing a Mono wav file, however the sound is dirty and has clickd etc throughout

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Close-voters: this was not a typographical error, it was an actual mathematical error involving overflow and how to prevent it.  It should stay open.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, what is the datatype of `audiodata`? I assume it's some fixed-width integer format and you therefore get overflow. If you convert it to a floating point format before processing, it will work fine:

```
audiodata = audiodata.astype(float)
```

Second, don't write your Python code element by element; vectorize it:

```
d = (audiodata[:,0] + audiodata[:,1]) / 2
```

or even better

```
d = audiodata.sum(axis=1) / 2
```

This will be vastly faster than the element-by-element loop you wrote.

Comment: Why not `audiodata.mean(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 3):

turns out, all i had to change was

(right+left)/2

to

(right/2) + (left/2)

Comment: Shouldn't you accept the answer you went with?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix not when the accepted answer is better. Converting to a float saves some loss when the integers are odd

Answer (score 0):

After applying the mean you have to save the file with data as int16

`wavfile.write(newfilename, sr, np.int16(newaudiodata))`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This should work. You take first channel from stereo data:

```
audiodata = [s[0] for s in audiodata]
```